# Firefox positioning doesn't work with table-cell

Tags: css, firefox, positioning, css-tables

I have one div displaying as *table-cell* and I want to position the another one relative to the first one. But it doesn't work in Firefox.

Open this link in Firefox please, and see the difference. How can I fix it?

http://jsfiddle.net/JFAbM/

I saw someones didn't understand what I need exactly. So I updated the code. I need to position the light gray block.

http://jsfiddle.net/JFAbM/7/

Guys, I have already solved it with wrapping extra div

Ex. here jsfiddle.net/JFAbM/8

Comment: It works fine if you change the display of "aa" to block or inline-block.

Comment: I know, but I need 'table-cell'

Comment: I fixed it by wrapping extra div, see http://jsfiddle.net/JFAbM/8/

Answer (score 1):

just change the `position:absolute` to `position:relative`, no need to wrap any extra div

see this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JFAbM/2/)

**update** : http://jsfiddle.net/JFAbM/5/

Comment: with rlative posiitoning it prevents centering the image (which is in table-cell) vertically

Comment: Can You plz explain me a little bit more what do you want exactly?

Comment: Wrapping the extra div is only solution. To keep vertical centering I wrapped it not in, but over table-cell

Answer (score 1):

Replace `position:absolute;` with `position:relative;`

Check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JFAbM/9/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm also searching for an appropriate solution. As jumancy pointed out and as far as I can see you will need a wrapper-element:

```
<table>
<tr>
     <td><div class = "relative-wrapper">
            <!-- Other stuff goes here -->
            <div class = "pos-abs">Be relative to me, wrap me, show me on hover!</div>
            <!-- or here -->
     </div></td>
</tr>
</table>


//CSS
.relative-wrapper{
   position: relative;
   display: block;
}
.pos-abs{
   position: absolute;
}
```